# Extract Values from stdclass object in php

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I have a stdclass object as below in PHP :-

```
$sample = (object) array(
             "sname" => "test"
             ,"bselection" => "12345"
             ,"bind" => "1"
    );
```

I need the output as below -

test123451

Please advise how I can I get the output as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you casted it as an object upon declaration, just access it like any other normal object, thru `->` arrow operator:

```
echo "{$sample->sname}{$sample->bselection}{$sample->bind}";
```

Several versions will work as well using `.` or `,`:

```
echo $sample->sname,$sample->bselection,$sample->bind;
```

Comment: I have a question about the difference between 1st and 2nd answer which one is better to use **{ }** or simply **.** dot .

Comment: @NarendraSisodia it just solely depends on how you'll use it, when you wrap it with double quotes in conjuction with `{}`, you allow those values to be interpolated inside. like `echo "{$test} <br/> <h1>another string</h1> \$literal_string";` in this mixed up value, you don't need to break the quotes. actually, its just preference, i just like the quoted one. so that i don't need to break quotes each time. `echo $test . "<br/> <h1>another string</h1>" . $another_var . "test";`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $sample->sname.$sample->bselection.$sample->bind;
```

Try this.
You can simple access an object using -> sign and dot . sign to concatenate it.